# Is it possible to assert an error case in HUnit?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, hunit

If I have a function which results in an error for a certain input, is it possible to write a test verifying the error occurs for that input?

I do not find this "assert error" functionality available in [HUnit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-1.6.0.0/docs/Test-HUnit-Base.html). Is it available in HUnit or perhaps in some other test package?

Comment: The `HUnit-Plus` package provides [`assertThrows`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-Plus-2.0.0/docs/Test-HUnitPlus-Base.html#v:assertThrows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch an error and assert if it doesn't happen using standard exception handling:

```hs
errored <- catch (somethingThatErrors >> pure False) handler
if errored then
    assertFailure "Did not catch expected error"
else
    pure ()
where
   handler :: ErrorCall -> IO Bool
   handler _ = pure True
```